# jQuery validator addMethod always displays an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.validator.addMethod("uniqueEmail", function() {

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "/user/check_email",
        data: {
                email: $( "#email" ).val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data == 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

     })

}, "That email already exists");

email: {
                    required: true,
                      email: true,
                      uniqueEmail: true
            }
```

I don't know why the uniqueEmail always displays an error even if I return true or false, what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your ajax call is asynchronous and the function you give to `.addMethod()` needs to return a value right away.

But don't be tempted to set `async: false`. Use [remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method) instead.

I believe it would look something like this:

```
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
        url: "/user/check_email",
        type: "post"
    }
}
```

When the ajax call is made by remote method, it will automatically include a parameter named "email" with the value of the email input, so you are good there. You just need to change the server code so it returns `"true"` or `"false"`, rather than `"0"` or `"1"`. (Note: You return `"0"` to indicate the email is not in use, which means it is unique. You should now return `"true"` in that case.)

UPDATE:

You've accepted this answer, but to follow up on how you can specify the error message, you might be able to leave your server response just how it is by using the following:

```
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
        url: "/user/check_email",
        type: "post",
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            return (data == 1) ? "true" : "That email already exists";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but I can't handle that remote method, because I don't know how to set the error message depending of the server answer true or false, thats why I've used addMethod, because there I can set an error message, by default its show me "fix this field"

Comment: It sounds like you get the default message if you return "false", but if you return any other string  (other than "true") that string will be used as the error message.

Comment: so where do I return that string? using the remote function?

Comment: I believe you return it from the server, rather than returning "false".

Comment: I think there is another way to specify the error message. When you call `.validate()`, you can provide the following property in the `options` object: `messages : { email: { remote: "Your custom message" } }`

Comment: @yeahitsme - You're welcome. I'm curious though if the code in the update works for you. Let me know if it does.

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous function that you pass to `addMethod` isn't returning a value. You're using the jQuery ajax handler which uses a function on `success`. Your `return` statements are inside this function.

Answer (score 0):

The response from the server is given asynchronously. Try to add `async: false` to your options according to [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**EDIT**

And as said @BotskoNet you're returning the value inside an anonymous function.